# React Saving extra details for Firebase method createUserWithEmailAndPassword()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I had a problem, when I want to save extra details like user name and user's phone number, I can't do so, so far my code is

```
function saveUser(user) {
return ref.child(`users/${user.uid}`)
    .set({
        email: user.email,
    })
    .then(() => user);}

export function register(email, pw) {
return firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
    .then(saveUser);}
```

I want to be able to save details like so that in my register function I would have register(email,pw,name) and then save all of the details with the saveUser function, how can I do so? I put this code in services folder and want to connect it to the user model in which I used this method as shown below

```
export function signUpAndWaitEmailVerification(email, pw) {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(beginSignUp());

    return register(email, pw)
        .then((user) => {
            user.sendEmailVerification().then(
                () => {
                   dispatch(signUpSuccess('You are one step away! Check your Email and Verify your account!'));
                });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch(signUpError('The email is invalid or has been used by other user'));
        });
};}
```

Comment: What's the error? Shown up? Code looks okay.

Comment: I want to save extra details but I could not work around it, it always goes into the error part. @UmarHussain

Comment: Does the user parameter come into the saveUser function properly?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I think so, how do you know if it comes properly?

Comment: You could add this to top of saveUser function for testing only:  if (user == null) { alert('user is null'); }

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I tried putting that code on top and it is not null